# Issues adding objects before/after in double linked list

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to add items to a double linked list and I'm try to add them in the correct order defined by comparing their strings.

```
   public boolean add(Book book)
{
    Node current    =   new Node(book);

    if(firstNode == null)
    {
        firstNode   =   current;
        lastNode    =   current;
        numElements++;
        return true;
    }


    else
    {
        Node tempNode   =   firstNode;
        int val = -1;
        while(tempNode != null)
        {
            if(tempNode.bookElement.compareTo(book) > 0)
            {
                val = 1;
                break;
            }

            else if(tempNode.bookElement.compareTo(book) == 0)
                    return false;
            else
            {
                val = -1;
                tempNode    =   tempNode.next;

            }
        }


            if(val > 0)
            {
                System.out.println("next: " + tempNode.bookElement.getISBN());

                current.next        =   tempNode;
                if(tempNode == firstNode)
                    tempNode.previous   =   current;


                 if(current.previous == null)
                    firstNode   =   current;

                numElements++;

                return true;
            }


            else
            {
                current.previous    =   tempNode;
                tempNode.next      =   current;
                lastNode            =   current;
                numElements++;
                return true;
            } 


    }

}
```

and here is how i'm adding the objects:

```
Book[] books    =   new Book[4];
    books[0]        =   new Book("a", "charles g", "book1");
    books[1]        =   new Book("b", "michael b", "book2");
    books[2]        =   new Book("c", "james k", "book3");
    books[3]        =   new Book("d", "gsdgsdgg g", "book4");


    BookList booklist =   new BookList();
    booklist.add(books[0]);
    booklist.add(books[1]);
    booklist.add(books[2]);
    booklist.add(books[3]);
```

**The objects are compared using the String compareTo on the first parameter i.e  "a" or "b"**

At the moment I can get the the list to sort properly if I switch the order i.e "a" = "d", "b" = "c" etc, but if I keep it in it the way it is now and try sort i get a null pointer on:

```
tempNode.next      =   current;
```

if I make the line

```
while(tempNode != null)
```

to

```
while(tempNode.next != null)
```

then the list sorts in order and I can keep it as a,b,c,d. But I'm wanting to be able to sort it correctly regardless of the order I add them in so I think there is something very wrong in the way I'm adding them.

EDIT:

I got the list adding backwards so adding d,c,b,a first works as intended since it wasn't checking the if statements in the while block for the first node since the first nodes next was null so I put it into a dowhile so that it checks it, but I am still getting a null pointer when I try to run it normally by a,b,c,d. The null pointer is happening on the while(tempNode.next != null)

```
do
        {
            if(tempNode.bookElement.compareTo(book) > 0)
            {
                val = 1;
                break;
            }

            else if(tempNode.bookElement.compareTo(book) == 0)
                    return false;
            else
            {
                val = -1;
                tempNode    =   tempNode.next;
            }
        }

        while(tempNode.next != null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code fails to add nodes to the end of the list, since in that case `tempNode` becomes null, and `tempNode.next` gives you `NullPointerException`.

You should change your condition to `while(tempNode.next != null)`, but if after the loop `val < 0`, you have to compare `current` to `tempNode`, to determine whether `current` should be inserted before or after `tempNode`.